# Getting value from json array in java

Tags: java, json

How can i get value from json array in java 
Output

```
{
    "result": "success",
    "from": "USD",
    "rates": {
        "AUD": ((AUD in terms of USD)),
        "BGN": 1.8096,
        "BRL": 3.1143,
        "...": 1.3113,
        "...": 7.473, etc. etc.
    }
}
```

How do i get the value of "BGN"

Comment: Don't post code in a comment. it's unreadable. Instead, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54963310/edit) your question and add the code.

Comment: Or better yet, answer your own question. That's perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

What you have above is not a JSON array.

JSON arrays looks like this:

```
{
 "this-is-an-array": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
}
```

What you have above are properties of an object designated to the property rates.
Think of JSON as a Map of Maps and Arrays.

Below, I show you how you can iterate the properties in JavaScript.
It may look like its an array but its actually a map that you access providing the key:

```js
var json = {
    "result": "success",
    "from": "USD",
    "rates": {
        /* "AUD": ((AUD in terms of USD)), This is not JSON. It is something else */
        "BGN": 1.8096,
        "BRL": 3.1143,
        "...": 1.3113
    }
};

for(var prop in json.rates){
  console.log("Key: " + prop + ", Value: " + json.rates[prop]);
}
```

Comment: Let me know if this helped you out. Else, we can try something else.

Comment: no sir.its an api that returned the array,i want to get the value of "bgn"

Comment: @kingsleyokola, I provided the solution based on the JSON that you provided. If the JSON you are getting its different then please update your question with it.
Now... If you wish to obtain ONLY the BGN value, then you can do  json.rates["BRL"] or json.rates.BRL. That's it.